# MongoDB background Indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing

As per the available articles background index does not lock the collection when an index is created, so ideally this should be a case when we are creating an index on a collection that already exists and has enormous data, would creating a background index on any new collection which is initially empty make any difference over the default non-background index.

Thanks,
Vaibhav

Answer (score 1):

It won't make any difference for empty collections or even small collections. Also MongoDB ensures that after the indexes have been built, background and foreground indexes behaves same.